# Why did the diverted Rome - Chicago flight dump its fuel?

Tags: fuel

Having just read [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-northern-ireland-33226740) story about a plane which was diverted to Belfast following a passenger's abusive and threatening behaviour, I was wondering why the plane had to dump its fuel (as explained in the news article). It seems quite wasteful, surely the airline would prefer the crew to pacify or apprehend the passenger and carry on to its destination.

Comment: half dupe to http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2854/609 (about dumping fuel) and the other half is related to this: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8486/609 (not a dupe though)

Comment: Full dupe I'd say! Not sure how my searching didn't find this. The answers to that question address my point perfectly. Shall I delete this?

Comment: The airline would prefer the crew to pacify the passenger, but keep in mind that the crew members are not trained security guards and have limited options for restraining an unruly passenger.